# how to get a unique record from select query in mysql each time

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch random record from the table but repeated game id record is will become out only once at a time. I am sending a screenshot of my table

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the query what you are tried?

Comment: Do not post table structure + code as image.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why does your current approach not work

Answer (score 3):

You need to use MySQL [RAND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM lessons_game ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
// Put proper fields instead of *
```

**Explanation:**

`ORDER BY RAND()` will shuffle records random records from DB Table.

And we will get random records after we execute the query result set.

We are putting `LIMIT 1` so only one record will be pulled out.

Comment: @Cid, corrected now :)

Comment: it will be giving only 1 record randomly but i did not want this. i want all rows from table but repeated game id (in my case game  id 1 )whose question is father in  one case and the cat  is another  question . I want  record always unique record and when webuse delect query next time then question will be diffrent each time. PLease see attached  image

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command

```
SELECT * FROM lessons_game ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You should explain why this works as well, for complete answer.

Comment: i want to fetch all records but repeated game id record will be fetch only one at a time every time we use select query so please do not use rand() function